# A better $.ajax().always() (aka complete)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I often find myself consolidating jQuery ajax error and success results similar to the following:

```
$.ajax(
  success: function (response, statusText, xhr) {
    handleResponse(true, xhr, statusText, response, callback);
  },
  error: function (xhr, statusText, response) {
    handleResponse(false, xhr, statusText, response, callback);
  });
```

This is usually because handling a state change is necessary regardless of the result, but dependent upon it - it is clearer to show this state change being called only once. Also, I often reallocate certain 'success' responses to error handling, depending on specific response contents (such as an error contained in JSON results). I may also consolidate success-type actions from errors of certain types. It especially improves clarity to consolidate when these concerns interact with each other.

My main question is, **is there a better way to handle this error/success consolidation?**

A related question would be, is there some reason the jQuery authors seem to intentionally make this sort of use inaccessible, such as by changing the parameter order between success/error callbacks, and not providing access to the `isSuccess` internal result in the jqXhr result?

EDIT: I'm aware of the `complete` option (similar to the `always()` deferred I mentioned in the title). However, it does not provide access to the success/error HTTP status code rollup (`isSuccess` internally to jQuery, mentioned above), nor does it deserialize JSON on success.

EDIT 2: I've just discovered the excellent `jqXHR.isResolved()` that can be used to test the success status of the xhr, which only leaves manual deserialization of the response. **Unfortunately** it is listed as deprecated, although jQuery still uses it internally.

EDIT 3: jqXHR.state(), from the `deferred` prototype, seems to give me the success/fail status of a completed request when inspected from `.always()`. It looks a little dicey, like there is no by-design sequence guarantee on the value of this state when processing events. So perhaps subject to change. Also, using `.always()` in this manner still leaves me to deserialize/interpret the received data manually.

---

Maybe you think I'm crazy for wanting to do this. Maybe you are correct; you be the judge. The example that has my back up at the moment is that I'm trying to add a transparent authentication retry queue to my ajax calls:

```
    this.exec = function (callback, parameters) {
        queue.add({
            url: settings.url,
            type: settings.post ? 'POST' : 'GET',
            data: parameters && parseInt(parameters) == parameters ? { id: parameters } : parameters,
            success: function (response, statusText, xhr) {
                handleResponse(true, xhr, statusText, response, callback);
            },
            error: function (xhr, statusText, response) {
                handleResponse(false, xhr, statusText, response, callback);
            }
        });
    }
    function handleResponse(success, xhr, statusText, response, callback) {
        if (settings.authRetry && xhr.status == 401) {
            authRetryQueue.notify(xhr);
        }
        else {
            queue.remove(xhr);
            if (callback) {
                if (success) {
                    if (xhr.method == 'GET' || response.StatusText == null || response.StatusText == 'success')
                        callback(true, settings.Model ? new settings.Model(response) : response);
                    else callback(false, response.StatusText);
                }
                else {
                    callback(false, response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `(such as an error contained in JSON results).`  - this is the x in your XY problem. Use HTTP status codes instead of putting error codes in JSON.

Comment: use the `complete` handler if you want them all in one. see the api docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: hmmmm, cant say i quite understand your problem as i always design my backend to NEVER hit $.ajax.error. If I hit `error`, then something on my backend is designed wrong and needs to be redone. I handle all "errors" via my return to the `$.ajax.success` call, thus negating this issue all together. Thus my return is either a string saying "success/error" or an object with a property of "Status" stating "success/error" and, as formentioned, negating the whole `.error` handle all together.

Comment: scrappedcola, the complete handler doesn't inform with success/fail rollup, nor does it deserialize JSON

Comment: benjamin, notice how your answer is directly at-odds with SpYk3KK. Both are valid. if all errors are treated as HTTP errors, as you suggest, then I still have to manually deserialize JSON to populate my local viewmodel with error information. besides, I'm not talking about outright failures in all cases. in some cases they are "errorish", where a subset of the UI actions are still performed.

Comment: SpYk3HH, I can't prevent network errors, server failures, and the like.